# Joint distribution where one of the random variable is discrete

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be uniform over $(0,1)$ and let $Y$ be a discrete random variable having Poisson distribution. Suppose $X , Y$ are independent. Let $Z = X + Y$. Show that $Z$ is a continuous random variable.

I came across this problem in my college previous year paper.

Tried to solve it.

$$ P[Z=z] = P[Z=x+y] =P[X=k , Y=z-k]$$

Limits will be $$ 0≤K≤1 \text{ and }z-k>0 $$

Now Limit for $K$ will be $$ 0≤k<z≤1 $$ Since $k$ is continuous can we stop here saying $Z$ is continuous? Or if we need to calculate pdf I tried using the below method but I am not sure if am on the right path.

$$ P[Z=z] =  \int_0^z \frac{m^{z-k}e^{-m}}{z-k!} \, dk $$

Not sure if I am on the right path and I am stuck not able to proceed. Need guidance here to solve the problem.

Comment: $\mathbb P\{Z=z\}$ is $0$. What you need to prove is that there is a function $f$ s.t. $\mathbb P\{Z\le z\}=\int_{-\infty }^z f(u)\,\mathrm d u$ for all $z$. Also, your first equation (i.e. $\mathbb P\{Z=z\}=...$ has no sense. You should rather use total probability formula here.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a \in [0,1)$.
$$P(Z \le n + a) = P(X \le n-1) + P(X = n, Y \le a) = P(X \le n-1) + P(X = n) P(Y \le a)$$
$$P(X \le n-1) + P(X = n) \cdot a.$$
Hence $P(Z \le x)$ is a continious function of $x$.